# Are there any memes on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, fun

Just curious. After reading about the infamous "Boat Programming" question, I wondered if anything like that has existed on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does "Jorge Castro the Bot" count?

Comment: There's also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80772/whats-the-deal-with-all-these-chuck-montages).

Comment: what is the boat programming question?

Comment: I think it basically went like this: "What kind of programming should I do on a boat?". The question was hard deleted from the database, because I guess a certain moderator hated the question so vehemently.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1900/is-jorge-castro-a-robot

Answer (score 37):

**Meme:** "pulling a terdon"

**Originator:** [terdon ♦](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon)

**Examples:**

> ["let's not pull a terdon"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32320011#32320011)
>
> ["Let's not pull a Terdon here."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=31969935#31969935)
>
> ["I promise to never pull a Terdon :p"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=23215222#23215222)

**Background:** Our dear friend (and moderator) terdon [inadvertently assisted a poor user in deleting his home directory](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/the-little-rm-that-could). Terdon was quick to own up to his mistake and as a friendly gesture, we refer to an "oops" moment as "pulling a terdon".

Comment: Just read the conversation. That's why you need to be careful instructing users via written chat.

Comment: Oh, you dirty little. . . :P

Comment: By the way, in my defense, the user in question had asked "How can Linux be cruel". I answered, never expecting they'd actually run the malicious command I had suggested :(

Comment: Oh my lord I can't stop laughing XD @terdon

Comment: @terdon, why is the command itself not shown in that chat history?

Comment: @Wildcard because I'd rather not pull any more terdons than absolutely necessary. I deleted it as soon as the unfortunate (and rather trusting) user ran it. If you really want to know, I had suggested adding a command that deletes everything in `~/` to `~/.bashrc`. I'm sure you can figure it out :)

Comment: I laughed so hard reading that :D

Comment: Using `>>` to append to `.bashrc` instead of overwriting it was a nice touch.

Comment: I see the part in the chat where Terdon says "DO NOT DO THAT!" but it's not clear where exactly it starts. Perhaps the comment by Terdon from November 2016 should be included in the answer?

Answer (score 20):

**Meme:** Zanna is awesome!

**Originator:** [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg), [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind), ...

**Examples:**

> [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg): [" @Zanna without any jokes, you're awesome. "](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32583390#32583390) (2016-09-27)
>
> [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind): ["ZANNA YOU ARE AWESOME"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32583512#32583512) (2016-09-27 ★8)
>
> [Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1): ["oh @Zanna, did you know you're awesome?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32597378#32597378) (2016-09-28 ★4)
>
> [Kaz Wolfe](https://askubuntu.com/users/208574/kaz-wolfe): ["Also, @Zanna is awesome."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32604381#32604381) (2016-09-28 ★5)
>
> [Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1): ["@jokerdino time for a website with just "Zanna is awesome" as content"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32622623#32622623) (2016-09-29)
>
> ...

**Background:** Well, [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) is awesome. That's it. We can't state that often enough. And we can't refrain from starring it.

Comment: come on now!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: http://zannaisaweso.me

Answer (score 16):

**Meme:** bacon

**Originator:** [George Edison](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=7396747#7396747)

**Examples:**

> ["I'd rather die full of bacon than not full of bacon."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=30968150#30968150)
>
> ["**BACON WRAPPED IN BACON.**"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31472019#31472019)
>
> ["They may take our GitHub. They may take our projects. They may even take our dignity. But they will never take our bacon!"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32705088#32705088)
>
> ["Is Jono Bacon the closest thing Ubuntu will ever have as bacon?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=6273356#6273356)

**Background:** yonder over on the Ask Ubuntu General Room, we love our bacon. It is delicious. It is awesome. It is the pinnacle of perfect foods. It also tends to attract a lot of stars.

Comment: I miss jono bacon... ;__;

Comment: “ It is the pinnacle of perfect foods.”  would beg to differ.

Answer (score 12):

**Meme:** The Starboard

**Originator:** Ask Ubuntu Chat

**Examples**:

> ["Lol"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32567108#32567108)
>   ["Yeah, people here will star any old thing. Here, just watch."](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=31851832#31851832)
>   ["<s>test</s>"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32000453#32000453)
>   ["Star this, for no reason at all."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=35159188#35159188)
>   ["."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34622291#34622291)

<sup><sub>(yes, that last one is a single dot)</sub></sup>

**Background:** The absolute easiest place to get the [Outspoken](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/74/outspoken) badge is right here in Ask Ubuntu General, because literally *anything* will get starred just because it exists. This has led to many debates about removing the star board, because it serves no more purpose than the generic transcript.

Comment: **★ 5** Ma precious stars! Noooooo!

Comment: A synonym for this could be the 'starwall' too, I've seen it called both.

Comment: Is it called the starboard because it appears on the [right side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_and_starboard) of the chat page? :)

Answer (score 11):

**Meme:** Chaos / Darkness (and other joinings of these two)

**Originator:** [Thomas Ward](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward)

**Background:** In recent days, one of our moderators, [Thomas Ward](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward) took some D&D tests to determine his alignment, and ended up Chaotic Neutral/Evil.  He's since taken a liking to the terms "Chaos" and "Darkness" in regular greetings, or when doing some moderator-ly actions.  A regular greeting, in place of "Hello" or "Good day" from Thomas, is "Good Chaos to thee" or "Good Darkness to thee" or similar, and is mostly the origin of this meme.  Due to the origin of this being one of our Moderators, Thomas is sometimes called "The Dark One" or "The Chaotic One" solely because of the adoption of these terms in regular messages from him.

**Examples of Originator Invocations:**

> - ["Good Chaos to thee!"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35503021#35503021) (sometimes written with Darkness instead of Chaos)
> - ["***A great Darkness has swept through the flags queue, and cleared most of it away with Flames of Evil and Darkness.***  *Darkness Moderator returns to the shadows from whence he came*"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=35263648#35263648)
> - [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg): ["And Good Darkness to you as well"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35507357#35507357)
> - [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind): ["all hail Chaos!"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35507374#35507374)

**Examples of Community invocations:**

> - [jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino): ["Darkness shall prevail"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35503312#35503312)

---

And just because I should probably show these, some typical community responses to the "Good Chaos to thee" greetings:

> - [ByteCommander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander): ["May Darkness lead your ways."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35503169#35503169)
> - [Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg): ["Good morning, Mr. Dark-One"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35503043#35503043)

Comment: Since nobody ELSE would put this up there and it's been said that it's a wonder I'm not up here on the meme list for this, I thought I'd create this since nobody else will.

Comment: Eh, I'd just lock the whole post. Is there even a point to this? Most, if not all, of these are only seen in chat. How many of these are actually seen on the site itself, where a passing user might see them and wonder, "what is this meme"?

Comment: @muru I'm sure some of them are used on the main site too (I've seen it a few times) but there's no good way to search comments and something like this isn't likely to be in an answer (nor should it).

Comment: @Seth why not in answers? For example, one meme I have seen a few times in answers of [codegolf.se] is the "Crossed out 44 is still regular 44" one. When I saw that a couple of times, I went looking for their meta's meme post. That's an instance of actual usefulness of a meme list, which I don't think this post ever had or will have.

Answer (score 11):

**Meme:** Getting Eliah'd

**Originator:** FEichinger (??)

**Background:** [Eliah Kagan](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) is known (and loved) for posting long and well researched answers on both main and meta.  His answers are so long and well researched that you don't bother disagreeing with Eliah, you just admit he has you beat.  If you are writing an answer when Eliah posts one, there's no point.  He will have covered everything you were going to say. (all of this in the best way possible)

**Examples:**

> - [Eliah Eliah'd the chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8912772#8912772)
> - [Off-topic. It's on Mint. Personally I think cinammon on Ubu should be OT too, but it's not. Watch as I get Eliah-ed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8755296#8755296)
> - [I do love how Lightness' answer gets Eliah'd, though.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8852557#8852557)
> - [I got Eliah'd.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8747120#8747120)
> - [**Eliah'd!**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8846372#8846372)

**Variants:**

> - [I almost don't bother to answer a meta question because I know Eliah's answer will come and it's gonna be way better than mine. I feel people accept my answer out of sympathy XD](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8841267#8841267)
> - [I like to think we could all just abandon meta and have Eliah answer everything. Would have the same effect.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8841265#8841265)
> - [That was the point at which I started telling myself "Eliah posted. Just stop. You can't win this one."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=8747146#8747146)
> - [Yay, an Eliah answer.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=14203318#14203318)
> - [With all due respect, you have not applied this line of thought elsewhere. You've answered non-Ubuntu-specific questions here, here, here, here, here, here, here, here, here, and here, just for starters. - Eliah Kagan](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5688/lets-reopen-this-on-topic-question-about-using-ubuntu-software-in-ubuntu/5691#comment8242_5691)
> - [Thanks. I channeled my inner Eliah there a bit.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36043845#36043845)

Answer (score 10):

**Meme:** nubcake

**Originator:** [edwinksl](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34406892#34406892)

**Examples:**

> ["rare to see seth be such a nubcake"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34406892#34406892) -- **Originator**
>
> ["at least im not a nubcake like @Seth"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34431944#34431944)
>
> ["If you're alive, you're a nubcake. No exceptions."](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34686410#34686410)
>
> ["Yep, and I can't. I'm probably gonna be like "lol gtfo nubcake, ban hammer in yo face"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34783257#34783257)

**Variant Forms:**

> ["Oops. I've been nubcaked."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35113067#35113067)
>
> ["Speaking of which. What manner of nubcakery is this?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35113012#35113012)

**Background:** Our Glorious <s>Leader</s> Moderator Seth [made a mistake](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34406856#34406856), prompting edwinksl to call him a nubcake. The meme then spread to be a Seth-specific meme, but then jumped to other people in time, and is now a badge <s>of honor</s> in the Ask Ubuntu General Room.

Answer (score 9):

**Meme:** systemd is evil

**Originator:** [htorque](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=1020460#1020460)

**Background:** systemd is not generally well-liked by everyone in the room. In fact, due to its invasive nature, systemd is generally well-*hated*. It is used as the brunt of jokes and blamed for all things wrong in Ubuntu.

**Examples:**

> - ["*Glares in systemd's corner...*"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=20643544#20643544)
> - ["Systemd just kills all of our hopes and dreams."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=30168208#30168208)
> - ["I have a good reason for screaming: systemd"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=30991394#30991394)
> - ["when in doubt, blame systemd :)"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=31150074#31150074)
> - ["systemd can make your bed, cure the common cold, and perfect nuclear fission. Or so we're told."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32633960#32633960)
> - ["WHAT? SYSTEMD CHANGES LIGHTBULBS NOW? IS THERE NO END TO THIS INSANITY?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33145757#33145757)
> - ["Did someone just use "fix" and "systemd" in the same sentence?"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34621851#34621851)
> - ["**Oh how I hate the GUTS out of systemd!** It's a flaming pile of garbage straight from /dev/null."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transript/201?m=34745169#34745169)
> - ["Because systemd.™"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=35287359#35287359)

Comment: Is it a meme if it's true tho?

Answer (score 6):

**Meme:** hue

**Originator:** [TheWanderer](http://askubuntu.com/users/274320/thewanderer)

**Background:** if someone is being an exceptional [nubcake](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16602/5), a user may immediate reply with "hue", a reference to [this meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/huahuehuahue). Bonus <s>points</s> stars for creating a pun with the word.

**Examples:**

> - ["Cue the glue whose hue gave Sue her due."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=36656287#36656287)
> - ["never gonna hue you up, never gonna hue you down, never gonna hue around, and hue you"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=36441917#36441917)
> - ["Oh say can you hue . . .by the dawns early lights"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=36433700#36433700)
> - ["Every time you say "hue," a v20 owner buys an iPhone."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=36198051#36198051)
> - ["Roses are red. Violets are blue. HUE HUE HUE HUE HUE."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=34251109#34251109)
> - ["I have a feeling that if you had written "How the Grinch Stole Christmas" you would have named the child Cindy Lou Hue."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=31995247#31995247)