# Ask Ubuntu Chat Twitter Bot

Tags: discussion, chat

For those of you who don't already know, we have a realtime chat room over at http://chat.askubuntu.com — lots of us (including a couple of moderators) hang out there. We help new users with their questions, we discuss Ubuntu topics, and we talk about bacon.

Once in a while, someone will say something absolutely hilarious:

> Maybe before I die, I will swallow a whole bag of popcorn kernels so that they get a surprise when they cremate my body! ;)
>     — [Terrance](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=29829534#29829534)
>
> Sir , your OS is a coward, I shall challenge thee to a duel of boots
>     — [Serg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=31687580#31687580)
>
> GTK+ 6 will just be one big button.
>     — [RolandiXor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=13105151#13105151)

Sometimes wise words of wisdom are spoken:

> When I hear 'if we can put a man on the moon we can do this' I'm hearing an analogy almost as if we're saying 'if we can put a man on the moon, well surely we can put a man on the sun'
>     — [Zacharee1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=28242769#28242769)
>
> if you give someone a script, you will frustrate them for a day... if you teach them how to write a script, you will frustrate them for a lifetime...
>     — [Zanna](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=32449663#32449663)

<sup>(Okay, maybe that last one was funny, but still sage advice.)</sup>

So...

Someone (I think it was Seth?) had the brilliant idea to capture these moments and share them with everyone via Twitter. Yes, we have [the starwall](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16192/5), but it's... a little overcrowded, to say the least. The messages that would be tweeted from this account would be hand-curated to ensure top quality.

That's when I stepped in and offered to write an app to...

[image]

More specifically, I wrote an app that scrapes the chat transcript and creates a list of messages that *might* be interesting. Then an actual human being goes through the list and chooses ones that are actually funny or really thought-provoking and queues them for tweeting.

Now I'm sure you all have questions, so...

### FAQ

**Where is this account?**
Here it is: https://twitter.com/ChattyCapybaras

**What is a capybara?**
This is a capybara:

[image]

**Why is it chatty?**
Chat... chatty... get it?

**Where is the app?**
It is hosted here: https://tbot.quickmediasolutions.com/

**Where do I register?**
You don't. The tweets are selected by a chosen few.

**Is this app open-source?**
Yes: https://github.com/AskUbuntu/tbot

**Why is it written in Go instead of [insert language here]?**
Because Go is awesome.

**Why is bacon awesome?**
Because it is.

**Are these *really* frequently asked questions?**
They are now that you're reading them.

Comment: +1 for the FAQ !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the love of all that is holy, PLEASE remove the bacon trigger. If you want to know why, [see here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32790962#32790962). Our mods' sanity is already stressed enough. They don't need to sort through a board of 8500 posts mentioning the word "bacon."

Otherwise, I'm very excited for our new robot <s>overlords</s> assistants in chat. Our highlights reel is gonna be fun!

Comment: It worked until you guys started exploiting it.

Comment: @NathanOsman Lesson learned.

Comment: It's not like I compiled it into the application (well, except as a default). Any staff member can change the triggers.

Comment: Slight sidenote - Mods != staff for the app. This is a completely separate venture.

Comment: @KazWolfe you were the worst offender in this.

Comment: I've removed those triggers.

Comment: @Seth What were the bacon triggers??