# What to do when there's a much better answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Case in point, [Unable to locate package libc6-dev-i386](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947927/unable-to-locate-package-libc6-dev-i386/947931#947931)

Mine is the accepted answer but Eliah Kagan's is much better and is also a valuable teaching moment whereas mine is just not that...

- Can users change the accepted answer?

If not, please upvote Eliah Kagan's answer so it gets the visibility it certain deserves.

Comment: The OP can change the accept, if they want, no one else. Just leave a comment for them. It really makes no diffrence though, the accept only shows the answer thet helped the OP most, not that it is the best in any way.

Comment: OK, so please upvote the other one for better visibility. It's not fair as it is.

Comment: You should not ask people to vote for any answer here, it may cause more problems than not if the voting is detected as irregular. You answer only has one less vote but is two days older, give it time and, hopefully, the better answer will come out on top.

Comment: No, mine is the current accepted answer and has 3 votes whereas the other better answer has only 2. I'm asking to upvote the other one, not mine and I already commented asking the OP to change the accepted answer.

Comment: I personally think it's OK to say "I hope people upvote this great unappreciated answer" or at least hint "I think this is a great answer that deserves more attention" (a bounty for exemplary answer is just another way of doing that anyway), as long as it's not your own answer or part of some insidious campaign "upvote my friend's answer" which this very obviously is not. (Hey I even shamelessly ask for upvotes on my own answers when they're not actually my own work but community wiki answers made from OP's mistaken [SOLVED!] edits...etc)

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm glad you like my answer! However, there is nothing wrong with yours--it's good and I upvoted it myself, between when you posted it and when I posted mine. By accepting your answer the OP identified it as having helped them. Given the circumstances of their question and what they said, there's no reason to doubt it did. So this seems like the system working fine. Even when sorted by "votes"--which is the default order, but people can also select "active" and "oldest"--an accepted answer will continue to appear above answers of higher score, except when it is the OP's own answer.

Comment: The reason I liked and prefer it over mine is because mine answers the question but yours answers it even better -and- teaches something valuable in the process. It could be said I just gave them a "fish" and you gave then a "fishing rod and taught them how to fish". Reason why I think yours should have more visibility.

Comment: (BTW, there's a [technical Ask Ubuntu term](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11750/are-there-any-memes-on-ask-ubuntu/16760#16760) for this scenario)

Comment: Solved, they changed as suggested.